# Sharepoint link to Delve account

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting, delve

In the SharePoint list, I want to make a dynamic link to a Delve profile. I have a JSON like this:

```
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDark--hover",
    "title": "Otevřít v Delve",
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://eur.delve.office.com?p=' + [$email]"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "text-decoration": "none"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "OpenPane",
        "class": "ms-font-xxl"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In fact, it does redirect me to the profile, but it's showing me only a profile image and the rest of the page is empty.

Comment: What is the data type of your column?

Comment: The type is hyperlink

Comment: Why are you not using Person or Group column? it by default has all the user information in list view.

Comment: What exactly you are storing in hyperlink field? Email address of user or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The URL format for Delve profile of user is in below format:

```
https://<tenant-name>-my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=<account name>
```

Where `<account name>` is in `i:0#.f|membership|user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com` format.

In account name, `i:0#.f|membership|` this part is fix and rest of the part is email ID of user.

Encoding `i:0#.f|membership|` will give you `i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7C`.

So, you need to convert the link in above format so that it will redirect to delve profile of users.

**Considering you have an email address of user in `[$email]`**, use below code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "a",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDark--hover",
        "title": "Otevřít v Delve",
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "='https://<tenant-name>-my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7C' + [$email]"
    },
    "style": {
        "border": "none",
        "background-color": "transparent",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "text-decoration": "none"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "OpenPane",
                "class": "ms-font-xxl"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note**: Replace `<tenant-name>` with your tenant name.

Comment: It's kinda working, but I've just found out, that there's different "login email", which I need. I mean, instead of "[$email]" I would need something like "[$username]". But when I try that, the icon disappears. For example: for login, I'm using "firstname@tenant.com", but displayed email looks like "first.last@tenant.com"

Comment: Do you have any field/column with `username` name in your list? Also, in order to generate the dynamic link to profile either you will need an email or account name of user. it will not work with display name/full name.

Comment: I only have columns `firstname` and `lastname`, so do I have to make column `username`?

Comment: I am not sure how are able to login with `firstname@tenant.com`. As delve profile url is in `https://<tenant-name>-my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=<account name>` format. so, you will need the account name of user for sure.

Comment: Maybe for your case you can create a column (say, **LoginEmail**) with the data in format `firstname@tenant.com` and try using the json code like: `"href": "='https://<tenant-name>-my.sharepoint.com/PersonImmersive.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7C' + [$LoginEmail]"`

Comment: Don't know why, but when I replaced `[$email]` with `[$LoginEmail]`, the icon suddenly disappeared.

Comment: That is because there is something wrong with the JSON. why don't you just use the `[$email]` column? is there any particular reason?

Comment: In the list, there is an email of some person "first.last@company.com", column `[$email]`, but for login, he uses "first@company.com", that would be a column `[$LoginEmail]`, so in the URL, I would need `[$LoginEmail]`, but when I use it in JSON, the icon disappears.

Comment: Ok and as I earlier said, the delve profile url requires account name which includes the actual email address and not the email you are using for login. So, you will need the actual email address in this case.

Comment: Hi Jakub, have you tried my suggestions? Is it working for you now?

Comment: Hello, yes I did. It's working perfectly now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you. It will help others seeking for help in future to find the correct answer easily.